# How to track category,subcategory and product details in omniture?

Tags: adobe-analytics

How to track category, subcategory and product details that is being viewed by a user in Omniture sitecatalyst?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about groupging products into categories and so on, the best practice method with Omniture is to capture the individual products (e.g. SKU), and then manage the groupings of these through SAINT Classifications.

Basically this is a text file lookup which has your SKUs, along with the various categories etc you want to assign to each. You synchronise this with the SiteCatalyst GUI.

This works better than trying to record these groupings at the time the code fires.

Answer (score 1):

Your account should be configured with Site Section and Site Sub Section (and perhaps sub-sub section) properties. You should populate Site Section (s.prop2 in my configuration) with your category, and Site Sub Section (s.prop3 for me) with your subcategory.

You can send a product details in the s.products variable in the format of:

`s.products="Category;Product;Quantity;Price[,Category;Product;Quantity;Price]"`

When multiple products are purchased at once, you should separate each data set by a with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of tracking category, sub category and sub sub category. We can use evar4, evar5 and evar6.

```
evar4= "parent category";

evar5="sub category";

evar6="sub sub category";
```

If you are in parent category, then all these three vars have same value. 
if you are in sub category then evar4 holds parent category, evar5 and evar6 holds sub category name.
if you are in sub sub category then evar4, evar5 and evar6 holds first, second and third level of category name.